# pytorch compute pairwise difference: Incorrect result in NumPy vs PyTorch and different PyTorch versions

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, tensor, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have two arrays, and I want to calculate row-wise differences between every two rows of two matrices of the same shape as follows. This is how the procedure looks like in numpy, and I want to replicate the same thing in pytorch.

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> b = np.array([[3,4,5],[5,3,2]])
>>> c = a[np.newaxis,:,:] - b[:,np.newaxis,:]
>>> print(c)
[[[-2 -2 -2]
  [ 1  1  1]]

 [[-4 -1  1]
  [-1  2  4]]]
```

BTW, I tried the same thing using pytorch, but it does not work. Is there anyway we could accomplish the same thing in pytorch

```
>>> import torch
>>> a = torch.from_numpy(a)
>>> b = torch.from_numpy(b)
>>> c1 = a[None,:,:]
>>> c2 = b[:,None,:]
>>> diff = c1 - c2
>>> print(diff.size())
torch.Size([1, 2, 3])
```

I was actually looking for `torch.Size([2,2,3])`. (P.S. I also tried unsqueeze from pytorch, but it doesn't work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue arises because of using **PyTorch 0.1**. If using PyTorch 1.0.1, the same operation of NumPy generalize to PyTorch without any modifications and issues. Here is a snapshot of the run in Colab.

[image]

As we can see, we indeed get the same results.

---

Here is an attempt to reproduce the error you faced of getting incorrect result:

```
>>> t1 = torch.from_numpy(a)
>>> t2 = torch.from_numpy(b)
>>> t1[np.newaxis, ...] - t2[:, np.newaxis, ...]

(0 ,.,.) = 
 -2 -2 -2
 -1  2  4
[torch.LongTensor of size 1x2x3]

>>> torch.__version__
'0.1.12_1'
```

So, please upgrade your PyTorch version to **1.0.1**!

---

#### Digging more into for details:

The main reason why it didn't work in **PyTorch version 0.1** is that broadcasting was not completely implemented then. Basically, the tensor promotion to 3D, followed by a subtraction can be achieved in two steps as in (in version **1.0.1**):

```
>>> t1[:1, ] - t2
>>> tensor([[-2, -2, -2],   # t1_r1
            [-4, -1,  1]])  # t1_r2

>>> t1[1:, ] - t2
>>> tensor([[ 1,  1,  1],   # t2_r1
            [-1,  2,  4]])  # t2_r2
```

The results of above two operations put together by stacking rows in the order (t1_r1, t2_r1, t1_r2, t2_r2), after each of the rows being a 2D would give us the shape `(2, 2, 3)`.

Now, try doing the above two steps in version 0.1, it would throw the error:

> RuntimeError: inconsistent tensor size at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1501971235237/work/pytorch-0.1.12/torch/lib/TH/generic/THTensorMath.c:831

Comment: hey - you are sitting on more rep than me, but why an [image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)?

Comment: @modesitt I usually don't do this, but atm I don't have a PyTorch installation on my machine. Also, it's exactly the same code as OP. So, I guess no issues in this case :)

Comment: This is very strange. I tried running the code that you mentioned above, but I am still not able to get the results. May I know the version of pytorch installation? Mine is 0.1.12_1. I guess I just have to upgrade pytorch then

Comment: @PalashAhuja Indeed that's the case. Please see updated answer!

Comment: I think this should be a feature implemented in the previous versions as well. Never mind, I have updated pytorch and it seems to be working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PalashAhuja I added more information regarding this!

Answer (score 1):

I use the latest version of Pytorch 1.0.1. This solution works for me:

```py
a = torch.tensor([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
b = torch.tensor([[3,4,5],[5,3,2]])
c = a.view(1, 2, 3) - b.view(2, 1, 3)
"""
tensor([[[-2, -2, -2],
         [ 1,  1,  1]],

        [[-4, -1,  1],
         [-1,  2,  4]]])
"""
c.size()
"""
torch.Size([2, 2, 3])
"""
```